# Update array element data in tableview cell on button click

Tags: arrays, swift

im struggling to find a good solution for items amount in cart, i have functions to multiply and divide price of products, but i dont know how to store them properly and pass to another VC.
i want to somehow rewrite cell amount value every time i click the button or make any better solution, but i have no idea how to do it proper way (should i start using database solution to store such data as user cart?)
if you need something more to make this question clear just ask

my cart struct model:

```
struct Order:  Codable {
    let orderId: String?
    var amount: Int
    let id,name, description, image: String?
    let price : String?
}
```

function to multiply in tableviewcell file

```
@objc func inc(){
            var into = Int(amountLabel.text!) ?? 1
            into = into + 1
        amountLabel.text = "\(into)"
            let label = DefPrice.price.components(separatedBy: "р")
            let basevalue = Int(label[0])
            priceLbl.text = "\(basevalue! * into)р."
    }
```

and thats how i print items in next vc:

```
 var dishNames = savedItems.compactMap({ "\($0.name!) \($0.price!) \($0.amount)" }) // idk how to make amount work
        let list = dishNames.joined(separator: ",\n")
        CartItems.items = list
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: You should post more of your code. It would be helpful to see the entirety of your view controller. One question I have is what is CartItems and what is DefPrice?

Comment: both are structs
struct DefPrice {
    static var price: String = "" // standart item price
}
struct CartItems {
    static var items: String = "" // items to push from cart vc to another one
}

Comment: Create singleton class UserOrders and save your data in it vars and get this data from it vars. If you will use database -> create func fetchData and saveData in class UserOrders.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.